# Creating sequences in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I saw in articles that can we use functions rand() and floor() to create a sequences from 0 and 1

> mysql

`SELECT floor(rand(0)*2) 
 FROM security.users;`

```
+------------------+
| floor(rand(0)*2) |
+------------------+
|                0 |
|                1 |
|                1 |
|                0 |
|                1 |
|                1 |
|                0 |
|                0 |
|                1 |
|                1 |
|                1 |
|                0 |
|                1 |
|                1 |
|                1 |
|                0 |
+------------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

is there any another way to achieve this ?
*** i dont talk about auto_increment ;**

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do you want. How many numbers (bits?) you want to generate?

Comment: If you want to create random sequences of 0 and 1, then rand() seems like it might be a useful part of that

Comment: `rand()` looks like a straight-forward solution for this.

Comment: @Strawberry as i said , i want another way to do this

Comment: @GMB as i said , i want another way to do this , not rand and floor

Comment: What's wrong with what you've shown us here? _Why_ don't you want to use `rand()` and `floor()`? If we don't know why you don't like the obvious solution we can't very well offer alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the degree of randomness/predicatbility is not important, yes, there are other ways to generate a sequence of 1s and 0s.

For example, we could emulate pseudo-random generation of 0 and 1 by retrieving microseconds from the system clock at some intervals, assuming that the microseconds value will be even or odd fairly randomly, if we space out each call a little bit of time.

For example, something like this:

```
SELECT n.i
  FROM ( SELECT MICROSECOND(SYSDATE(6)) MOD 2 AS i, SLEEP(0.000001)
         UNION ALL SELECT MICROSECOND(SYSDATE(6)) MOD 2, SLEEP(0.000001)
         UNION ALL SELECT MICROSECOND(SYSDATE(6)) MOD 2, SLEEP(0.000001)
         UNION ALL SELECT MICROSECOND(SYSDATE(6)) MOD 2, SLEEP(0.000001)
         UNION ALL SELECT MICROSECOND(SYSDATE(6)) MOD 2, SLEEP(0.000001)
         UNION ALL SELECT MICROSECOND(SYSDATE(6)) MOD 2, SLEEP(0.000001)
       ) n
```

returns:

```
     i  
  ----
     0
     0
     1
     1
     0
     1
```

NOTE: this answer is "yes", there are other ways of generating 1s and 0s. This answer is not suggesting that the demonstration here is the *best* way. This is just an example of query that generates a series of 1s and 0s.

---

There are other expressions with `RAND()` that would generate a 0 or 1, e.g.

```
ROUND(RAND()*1000,0) MOD 2
```

Comment: No article that I know of. With MySQL, to get different time values within a MySQL statement, use `SYSDATE()` function not `NOW()` (NOW() function gets evaluated once at the beginning of statement execution, so all references in the statement return same value. Parameter 6 gets a return including fractional seconds e.g. `2019-10-30 14:49:28.064657`. The `MICROSECOND()` function extracts the fractional seconds. The `MOD` operator is modulo division, returns a remainder. Equivalent to the `MOD()` function.  MySQL Reference Manual  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/func-op-summary-ref.html